# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.unfinishedstubbingexception powerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

often when i use powerMockito i wrtie this sentences
`PowerMockito.doReturn(message).when(messageDAOMock.save(message));` i get **unfinishedstubbingexception** and i don't know why and hoy i can correct it. also i put

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MessageService.class)
public class MessageServiceTest{
    @Spy
    MessageService serviceToTest = new MessageService();

    @Spy
    IMessageDAO messageDAOMock = new MessageDAO();
```

and i am using this dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and also i use junit 4.

tihs error **sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't** but i don't find out why or how i can solve it

thanks and sorry for my english, it is not my native languaje

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem, the error is that in the parentesis,
it is not

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(message).when(messageDAOMock.save(message));
```

else

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(message).when(messageDAOMock).save(message);
```